# Ruby on Rails: calculate number of days using records in array and insert in another array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have an array which consist of some records fetched from the table.

Example record:

```
rec = ReworkCycle id: 6634, issue_id: 2651, status_id: 3, project_id: 14, created_on: "2013-05-29 07:41:06", old_status_id: 2
```

There are `n` such records in the array for each `issue_id`

Here `issue_id` and `project_id` is unique.

Consider I have records with following statuses in an array: format = status(id)

```
[assigned(2), testing(3), hold(13), assigned(2), testing(3), reopened(7), assigned(2), testing(3),reopened(7), assigned(2), hold(13), testing(3), approved(27)]
```

What I want is to subtract the dates of two statuses in the following way:

```
array << (assigned date - 1st reopened date) - hold date which is between assigned and 1st reopened date - assigned date or status next to hold
```

first assigned - first reopen and then subract the time of hold

second result will come between two reopened states.

```
array << (2nd reopen date - 1st reopen date) - hold state if any between 1st and 2nd reopen state dates - status next to hold state date

array << (approved date - last reopened state) - hold state date if any in this two states - status date next to hold state
```

reopened states can be of any count in an array.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I've formatted your question but I still don't understand what you're asking here.

Comment: Basically i am calculating cycle time between two states.

Comment: Please be more specific. You have an array of `ReworkCycle` objects, each with a `status_id` and a `created_on` field. What do you want to calculate?

Comment: i want to calculate difference of dates between particular status id as mentioned above, specifically difference between to reopen statuses.
so, i need solution in foll manner [[1st reopened - 1st assigned], nth reopen - [n-1]th reopen, approved - nth reopen]]

Comment: If you will see there are also hold status in between
hold status lies between first assigned date and first reopen date
so formula will be
[(first assigned date - first reopen date) - (status date which is next to hold date(which is assigned date) - hold date)

Comment: You've posted an example array in your question. Please add the desired output for this specific array (add indices for referencing the elements). I'm having difficulties understanding expressions like *"(first assigned date - first reopen date) - (status date which is next to hold date(which is assigned date) - hold date)"*